# android toolbar popupTheme vs theme

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

Often I see this declaration of Toolbar in layout files:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Why are there two attributes relating theming: theme and popupTheme?
What are the purposes of each of them?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

1. **popupTheme**

   Specifies the theme to use when inflating popup menus. By default, uses the same theme as the `Toolbar` itself.
2. **theme**

   It is simply the theme of `Toolbar`.

Comment: You just said what I needed

Comment: Thanks for **"By default, uses the same theme as the Toolbar"**. And could you please provide some citing sources for this?

Comment: yeah, Google needs to hire more technical writers. A lot of the latest documentation is very "diluted". (That's actually why I hate working with Firebase)

Comment: Now what is popup menu? :)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it's the menu you get when you tap the overflow icon (the three dots) in any toolbar.

Comment: I'm trying to switch between different themes for the `Toolbar` but nothing changes in the Android Studio's preview. What am I missing?